# Java EE dependency Injection when to use?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I'm new to this and I want to understand when is it appropriate to use DI in Java. Suppose I need to ping different networks with different ping parameters:

The class PingParams:

```
public class PingParams {
int timeout;
int retries;
}
```

The class PingResult:

```
public class PingResult {
int ttl;
boolean available;
}
```

The class PingService:

```
public class PingService {

private PingParams pingParams;

@Inject
public PingService(PingParams pingParams) {
    this.pingParams = pingParams;
}

public PingResult ping(String ip) {
    // ping using timeout and retries from pingParams
    return new PingResult();
}
}
```

The client:

```
public class Client {

@Inject
PingService pingService;

private List<PingResult> doPing() {
    List<PingResult> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ips = new String[] {"127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2"};
    for (String ip : ips) {
        PingResult pr = pingService.ping(ip);
        ret.add(pr);
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<PingResult> prs = new Client().doPing();
    System.out.println(prs);
}
}
```

I have 2 injection points:

1. I inject PingParams in the constructor of PingService.

Is this correct? I mean, the DI container can not know the timeout and retries to inject into the PingParams unless you create some "Produces" annotated method, even in this case, it seams a looot of work just to create an object! But of course you need to create several, one for every network, how do you do that with DI?

1. I inject PingService in the client.

Seems legitimate, but PingService depends on PingParams, which takes us to injection point number 1.

Seems to me like the only appropriate way to use DI is with classes which have no dependencies (therefore useless) or with very simple service classes where you pass all the dependencies as parameters to service methods. For example a PingService which accepts the ip and the PingParams in the ping method, again this class would have no dependencies...

Am I missing something? How can you use DI with these "data" classes, classes which contain only fields for keeping data (PingParams)? Are suppose to avoid DI in these cases? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general you should only use dependency injection for non-data classes. If you have classes that contain both data and non-data collaborators you can use [assisted injection](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

The ping params you talk about should indeed be bound to an instance on the start-up of your application and injected where necessary. For you example that is indeed much code but in the long run it keeps things nice and clean in bigger projects.

To summarize: bind PingParam when the application starts (as a Singleton for example), inject it into PingService, and create PingResult without DI (as you have done).

For Dependency Injection best practices, I recommend reading [Dependency Injection by Prasanna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398855X)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know if you'we seen this:   "I need to ping different networks with different ping parameters" problem may be mine since it's not exemplified. What I'm trying to say is that I need to have several instances of "PingParams" one instance per network I'm trying to ping, so how do I create these instances? Without DI it would be easy, just create PingParams instances and pass them to the constructor of PingService, again without using DI.  Using DI? I don't know how :)

Comment: Guice is pretty nice but in JavaEE there is Weld which is quite different.

Comment: I do not know weld. In Guice, it would use [Named bindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) if you name/know the networks. You could for example inject `@NetworkA PingParams params`. Otherwise if the list of networks is dynamic, I would use [Multibindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) to add as many as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about CDI/Weld.  Let's say your `PingParams` class were stored in the DB, as configuration loaded from some table.  It would make a lot of sense to abstract that away, and simply provide a producer method for the `PingParams` class that reads the data from the DB and provides back this data element.  It's not a bad idea to use a data object for this configuration, and provide a producer for it.

Comment: Thanks John, it's not yet clear to me where will I get these PingParams from, I only know they vary. Also I don't understand very well how do I make this method to be called at the right time, for an IP, since you don't control the creation using new. I will have to look into it.